# Problem with PowerShell Trim() which also trims off a letter before a backslash

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a problem with `.Trim()` in PowerShell.

so, here are my line of scripts.

```
$path = 'C:\Projects\20190412_Release111.22.S2.FP\PowerShell'
$trimpath = $path.Trim('\PowerShell')
Write-Host $trimpath
```

when trimming the '\Powershell' off the path, the output should be:

```
C:\Projects\20190412_Release111.22.S2.FP
```

but the actual output is:

```
C:\Projects\20190412_Release111.22.S2.F
```

which is missing the 'P' from the foldername of '20190412_Release111.22.S2.F', i wonder if the .trim() has variable length condition that is why it is also trimming off the 'P'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell Trim bug with String containing "< char >$< repeated char >"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209746/powershell-trim-bug-with-string-containing-char-repeated-char)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass characters to the [`Trim` function](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/trim-your-strings-with-powershell/) it will trim any string that fits the pattern.

It is removing the 'p' from your path because there is a 'p' in the input string you passed it. If you had for some reason multiple 'P' before the word "PowerShell" it would remove all of those too:

```
$path = 'C:\Projects\20190412_Release111.22.S2.FPPPPPP\PowerShell'
$trimpath = $path.trim('\PowerShell')
# trimpath is 'C:\Projects\20190412_Release111.22.S2.F'
```

In this case I think `$trimpath = $path.Replace('\PowerShell', '')` would be a better fit.

Comment: To be more precise it will trim any number of characters matching any of the passed [char[]]. I.e. doubling the `l` isn't necessary at all.

Comment: Wouldn't  Split-Path be a better solution for this than using the trim function?

Comment: Thank you, @Michael Hancock. It helped on my troubleshooting